# Register non-static C++ methods in Lua

Tags: c++, class, methods, lua, non-static

I'm trying to make a small C++/Lua system where I would create my objects and attach behaviors to them in Lua. Right now I'm using LuaWrapper (a small header with basic C++ to Lua stuff), my problem is that as far as I can see Lua only let me register static class methods (or non-static functions), a little research and I figured its because the Lua typedef expects a method with only one parameter `lua_State* L` and non-static methods have the implicit `this`.

I was hoping for a way to solve this without dependency on other libraries, all I need is non-static classes/properties in Lua, so I see no reason to use LuaBind+Boost or other heavy-dependant wrappers.

Comment: If it helps, I've set up an example project that uses LuaWrapper in a separate repository to demonstrate basic usage of the library. It can be found at https://bitbucket.org/alexames/luawrapperexample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LuaWrapper isn't meant to hook up directly to non-static functions in a class. I suppose it could be with some special trickery, but this is how I designed it to be used:

```
static int Widget_AddChild(lua_State* L)
{
    Widget* parent = luaW_check<Widget>(L, 1);
    Widget* child = luaW_check<Widget>(L, 2);
    if (parent && child)
    {
        lua_pushboolean(L, parent->AddChild(child));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// ...

static luaL_reg Widget_metatable[] =
{
    { "AddChild", Widget_Addchild },
    // ...
    { NULL, NULL }
};
```

I usually keep the non-lua stuff in a separate file. In this case Widget.cpp/hpp. Then I have a LuaWidget file which just contains bindings like these which I write as needed. (I also have a number of snipmate snippets to make writing these functions quick and painless. If you're using vim I'd be happy to share them)

Comment: so it's not meant to be OO or did I miss something?

Comment: On the C++ side of things, it's not meant to be very OO. It's designed to be just like writing normal Lua bindings for a C library. When you are coding in Lua though, you can use the functions you define in an OO way. e.g. `w = Widget.new(); w:AddChild(v)`

Answer (score 1):

You can make a static function that will accept an instance of the class and an argument and call that function on the instance:

```
void func_static(MyClass* inst, T arg) {
    inst->func(arg);
}
```

Then register a function to call that function as a metafunction so you can do in lua

```
blah:x(y)
```

which will call the function that will receive the userdata that `blah` contains, as well as the argument `y`, and call `func_static` with `blah` and `y`.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but I didn't understand the "Then register a function to call that function as a metafunction" part

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using toLua++ (http://www.codenix.com/~tolua/).

It can parse class definitions and output a c++ code file to make the non-static class members available in Lua.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at [LuaCppWrapper](https://github.com/ignacio/LuaCppBridge51). It's intended for simple bindings only. If you want a full fledged solution, maybe OOLua or Simple Lua Binder are what you need.